# How to conditionally query keys based on boolean in collection in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I have a collection of items.

Example structure:

```
{
    "_id" : "56bb6c33efedf80e0e01596b",
    "name" : "Item1",
   "price" : 102,
   "category" : "food",
   "date" : { ... },
   "description" : "Description",
   "__v" : 0
}
```

where `date` can be one of two things

1.

```
date : {
     "day_of_week" : "wednesday",
     "weekly" : true
 }
```

2.

```
date : {
    "end_date" : "20150122",
    "start_date" : "20150121",
    "weekly" : false
}
```

The `date` object is based on the `weekly` boolean.

My question is, how do i formate my query to search both types of date objects? I want to first check whether the weekly boolean it true or false then query date based on that. I have tried the code below by separating it into two separate conditions, but i cant seem to properly format the conditional.

```
Item.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        'price': {
            '$gt' : 0 , 
            '$lt' : 200 
        },
        'category' : food,
        'date.day_of_week': {
            '$cond': [
                $date.weekly,
                'wednesday',
                null
            ]
        },
        'date.start_date': {
            '$cond': [
                $date.weekly,
                null,
                20150121
            ]
        }    
   }
}], function(err, deals) {
    console.log(err, deals)
    res.send(deals)
})
```

So i am stuck on trying to query to separate keys in the `date` object based on the `weekly` boolean.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you can give [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) operator a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$cond` operator can't be used in `$match` as only query operators are allowed as stated in the comments below.

If your data is consistent in that all the `$date.weekly` boolean tells you is the keys present in the date subdocument, then a simple `$or` may take care of it:

```
{ $or: [ { date.day_of_week: 'wednesday' },{ date.start_date: '20150121' } ] }
```

And if you are not performing any other aggregations, this would be much simpler and faster as a query instead.

Comment: No, `$cond` can be used in `$project`, `$group` and `$redact` where it is actually mandatory. And generally anywhere where an expression can be evaluated as an argument. `$match` is the only exception since the only operators allowed are ["query"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/) operators of the same types available to `.find()`, since this is essentially the same thing. So right conclusion, but incorrect background information.

Comment: Hmmm.... Tried it in a $group stage and got the error that $cond isn't a valid $group operator.

Comment: Then your code and usage is at fault. I use it all the time, and there are many examples on this very site. Perhaps you should ask your own question. Most likely you tried to apply at "top level", where you need an accumulator. Inside an accumulator or as the grouping `_id` is just fine

Comment: Good to know. Must have made a simple error in testing it out that I didn't catch at the time.

Comment: using the `$or` operator solved my issue, thanks @metame